# League and Divisions problem (np-hard)

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, optimization, traveling-salesman

There is a *League*. And there are *Divisions*, that are the disjoint subsets of this *League*. There are **n** teams (unique locations are given, let's assume it's **x** and **y** for simplicity reasons). Every team must belong to exactly one *Division*. There are **min** and **max** - minimal and maximal amount of teams per division. Every team travels once to every other team inside one division. The target is to divide the league into divisions in a way, that the total traveling distance for the whole league is minimized.

Input:
**n** - amount of teams 
**min** - minimum teams per division
**max** - maximum teams per division
**teams** - array of teams (**name**,**x**,**y**)

Input example:
**n** = 10
**min** = 2
**max** = 3
**teams** = [{a,1,1},{b,2,1},{c,5,3},{d,9,8},{e,6,8},{f,5,1},{g,1,7},{h,6,6}{i,7,2},{j,2,7}]

Output:
**League** 

Output example:
**League** = [[a,b,c],[d,e],[f,g,h],[i,j]] 
 
One sub array stands for one division. It means that the teams a,b and c belong to one division and each of them will visit every other team from this division.
 
This is not the optimal solution

This is what an output of a real-world case could look like
  [image: The algorithms output]

I am struggling with selecting an algorithm for this issue. It is not a traveling salesman since we are not interested in simply visiting all of the locations. Neither the clustering approach is applicable since we need to keep the **min**
and **max** in mind and it's not what clustering does. What kind of algorithms can be used to tackle down this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Balanced k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_clustering) would probably work reasonably well here.  Unfortunately the true cost structure can't be modelled with this (or any clustering algorithm that I know of); you would need to instead use some increasing function of the distance from the cluster centroid (this could be just the distance itself, or e.g. a small positive power).  Balanced k-means will then try to cluster the teams into divisions in such a way that the sum of these per-team costs is minimised, while enforcing a hard upper bound (your **max**) on the number of teams in a division.  The chosen number k of divisions, as well as these upper bounds, implies a lower bound on the division size, though this won't necessarily agree with your desired **min**.  Hopefully, playing with the parameters a bit could get you close.

The idea is basically the same as regular k-means clustering, except that in the assignment phase, instead of assigning each point (team) to its nearest cluster (division), you solve an instance of the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) in which each team is represented as a worker and each division is represented as **max** job slots: this enforces that each division receives at most **max** teams.  The problem can be solved with e.g. the Hungarian algorithm.

There's a paper here, but it seems to be behind a paywall unfortunately: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-44415-3_4

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I ended up using this implementation : https://github.com/ndanielsen/Same-Size-K-Means

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a [local search optimization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(constraint_satisfaction)), such as hill climbing or simulated annealing.

The configuration describes the assignment of teams to divisions; and you can define a set of operations that can be applied to a configuration to change it to another one (e.g., pick two teams in different divisions and swap which division they are assigned to; pick a team in a division with at least min+1 teams, and move it to a division that has at most max-1 teams). Then, you can apply one of those algorithms to try to find an optimal assignment.

The problem is NP-hard (I suspect), so I don't expect any algorithm to be always efficient and always find the optimal solution, but this might give a "good-enough" solution.

To get better results, you might repeat it multiple times with different starting configurations.   Also, the choice of the initial configuration might be important to its success.  You might try using a clustering algorithm to generate a starting configuration (e.g., assign cluster centroids using k-means clustering, with that idea that each centroid reflects a single division, and then iterate over the centroids in a round-robin fashion and for each centroid, find the unassigned team that's closest to it and assign it to that division, until all teams are assigned).